# How to stuff together earliest date and or text

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to write a query and output to an excel file which outputs all of a members mortgages into a cell, but grabbing their earliest maturity date first.

**Table Creation**

```
CREATE TABLE mortgages
(
      PartyID varchar(30)
      , Balance varchar(30)
   ,AccountNum varchar(30)
      ,FullName varchar(30)
      ,MaturityDate date

);

INSERT INTO mortgages (PartyID, Balance, AccountNum, FullName, MaturityDate)
VALUES ('1', '100', '10000', 'Jane Doe', '2020-03-20' )
     , ('1', '1000', '10001', 'Jane Doe',NULL );
```

For example, my desired output would look like this for a each member:

`Jane Doe - Account#: 10000  Maturity Date: 2020-03-20   Balance: 100 Account#: 10001  Maturity Date: No Maturity Date   Balance: 1000`

If they have a mortgage with no maturity date, it would just set the date to output text like 'No Maturity Date'.

I have the query to output everything into one line, but for some reason it's setting some of members earliest maturity dates to 'No Maturity Date' when they indeed have a date.

My SQL query currently looks like this for:

```
 ;WITH Mtg AS(
    SELECT DISTINCT PartyID, 
    Balance,
    accountnum,
    fullname, 
    COALESCE(NULL,CAST(MIN([MaturityDate]) AS VARCHAR(30)), 'No Maturity Date'+ SPACE(2)) [MaturityDate]                
    FROM mortgages
    group by partyid, balance, accountnum, fullname)
```

After that, I would format it for output which looks like this:

```
    )
    , Mtg1 AS(
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            outputLogic.DescriptionList
        , SUM(M.Balance) OVER(PARTITION BY M.PartyID ORDER BY M.PartyID) AS TotalMaturingBalance
        , [MaturityDate]
        , M.[FullName]
        , M.PartyID
        FROM Mtg AS M
        CROSS APPLY(
            SELECT (STUFF((SELECT'| ' + [FullName] +'- '+ SPACE(2) 
                    + 'Account#: ' + [AccountNum] + SPACE(2) 
                    + 'Mat. Date: ' + [MaturityDate] + Space(2)
                    + 'Mat. Bal:'+ '$'+CAST(M.Balance AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + SPACE(2)
            FROM Mtg AS M1
            WHERE M1.PartyID=M.PartyID
            FOR XML PATH('') ), 1, 5, '')  ) AS DescriptionList
        ) outputLogic
```

I have my original script, which doesn't account for the 'No Maturity Date' text that's in production now.  When I run my edited script (the one I posted above), the same member which has both types of mortgages (maturity date and no maturity date) in the production script would have only the one correct Account # and Maturity Date, but in my edited script it would output just the Account # and 'No Maturity Date'

My question is, what would I need to change in my script to output the members earliest maturity date, and then 'No Maturity Date' in the same column for the member scenario I explained above?

In my edited version, the SQL I posted above, only the data for `10001` would be outputted, in the production version only the `10000` would be outputted.

My desired output would look like this:

```
 Jane Doe- Account #: 10000 Mat. Date: 2020-03-20  Mat. Bal:$100
 Account #: 10001 Mat. Date: No Maturity Date  Mat. Bal:$1000
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2fcfd/31)

Comment: Hi, welcome to the forum. It would help if you are able to set up a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example for database-related questions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @McNets Hi, I've created a table using SQLFiddle, but didn't know how to insert it into my edit.  Hopefully it makes it easier to see.

Comment: @McNets got it, thanks! It executes, but doesn't output anything. The CTE wasn't working for some reason, so I had to use temp tables.

Comment: I don't understand what is exactly the problem. Is there a problem with the order?

Comment: @McNets yes, I wanted to display mortgages that had a date first in the column, there were instances where it would only display 'No Maturity Date' when the member had both a date and no date assigned to the mortgage. I figured it out. The problem was with one of my joins.